# How to setup multiple crontab task in different time zone?

Tags: cron, timezone, debian

On my Debian 9 remote server which is located in different country (I don't have root/sudo access) I am trying to setup the following 3 different crontab tasks in my local timezone.

1. */10 * * * * /usr/bin/env TZ=Asia/Karachi /home/smo/pg/pg --silent -co pg_D.cfg
2. 00 01 * * * /usr/bin/env TZ=Asia/Karachi /home/smo/pg/pg --silent -co pg_M.cfg
3. 59 23 * * * /usr/bin/env TZ=Asia/Karachi /home/smo/pg/pg --silent -co pg_Y.cfg

(The "pg_D/pg_M/pg_Y.cfg" files generates html files with timestamps)

The 1st task is working fine and html output contains local timestamps but task 2 and 3 is not running at all.
I have also tried with CRON_TZ by adding CRON_TZ=Asia/Karachi on top of each crontab task but no luck.

I wonder why Task #1 runs but other two fails?
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem
Actually both jobs was running according to remote server time but not my local time.

The issue was with time setting.
When setting up a cronjob in different time zone with above method, we have to set the remote server time not our local time.

My remote server is in UTC -5, so I changed the time...
from

```
59 23 * * * /usr/bin/env TZ=Asia/Karachi /home/smo/pg/pg --silent -co pg_D.cfg
```

To

```
59 18 * * * /usr/bin/env TZ=Asia/Karachi /home/smo/pg/pg --silent -co pg_D.cfg
```

And now everything is working good.